# how to add a terms to a vocabulary by form?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm using drupal 7
I need to create a form that can add new terms to specific vocabulary.
Which function can do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link [taxonomy_term_save($term)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7)